# How can I remotely update a python script

Tags: python

How can I update a python script remotely. I have a program which I would like to share, however it will be frequently updates, therefore I want to be able to remotely update it so that the users do not have to re-install it every day. I have already searched StackOverflow for an answer but I did not find anything I could understand. Any help will be mentioned in the projects credit!

Comment: Hmm... being able to update software without users' knowledge sounds sketchy. Maybe look into pip and just publish newer versions of the software, users will be able to update their installs from there. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip

Comment: @AleksanderLidtke I agree it does sound malicious, however I have no intent of doing it without there consent. Whenever a new update is available they will be informed and asked if they would like to update it. Thank you also for the recommendation, I will look into it!

Comment: @AleksanderLidtke You mean, like Chrome? I don't think it's necessarily shady, but it might be good to display that an update has been done.

Answer (score 0):

A very good solution would be to build a web app. You can use django, bottle or flask for example.

Your users just connect to your url with a browser. You are in complete control of the code, and can update whenever you want without any action on their part.

They also do not need to install anything in the first place, and browser nowadays provide a lot of flexibility and dynamic content.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. I will look into that as well. Thank you!